# How to mock react-router context

Tags: reactjs, react-router, enzyme

I've got fairly simple react component (Link wrapper which adds 'active' class if route is active):

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const NavLink = (props, context) => {
  const isActive = context.router.isActive(props.to, true);
  const activeClass = isActive ? 'active' : '';

  return (
    <li className={activeClass}>
      <Link {...props}>{props.children}</Link>
    </li>
  );
}

NavLink.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object,
};

NavLink.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  to: PropTypes.string,
};

export default NavLink;
```

How am I supposed to test it? My only attempt was:

```
import NavLink from '../index';

import expect from 'expect';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

describe('<NavLink />', () => {
  it('should add active class', () => {
    const renderedComponent = mount(<NavLink to="/home" />, { router: { pathname: '/home' } });
    expect(renderedComponent.hasClass('active')).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

It doesn't work and returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isActive' of undefined`. It definitely needs some router mocking, but I have no idea how to write it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thanks @Elon Szopos for your answer but I manage to write something much more simple (following https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/pull/62):

```
import NavLink from '../index';

import expect from 'expect';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

describe('<NavLink />', () => {
  it('should add active class', () => {
    const context = { router: { isActive: (a, b) => true } };
    const renderedComponent = shallow(<NavLink to="/home" />, { context });
    expect(renderedComponent.hasClass('active')).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

I have to change `mount` to `shallow` in order not to evaluate `Link` which gives me an error connected with the react-router `TypeError: router.createHref is not a function`.

I would rather have "real" react-router than just an object but I have no idea how to create it.

Comment: Notice the braces around "context" being passed into shallow - I missed those initially and it took me a while to figure out why it was not working!

Answer (score 21):

For react router v4 you can use a `<MemoryRouter>`. Example with AVA and Enzyme:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import test from 'ava';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const mountWithRouter = node => mount(<Router>{node}</Router>);

test('submits form directly', t => {
  const onSubmit = sinon.spy();
  const wrapper = mountWithRouter(<LogInForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />);
  const form = wrapper.find('form');
  form.simulate('submit');

  t.true(onSubmit.calledOnce);
});
```

Comment: This works until you need update the props of the wrapped component. Calling `setProps()` only works on the root component, which is now the `MemoryRouter`

Comment: I guess it is impossible to find an universal way to test components. However, in the example above it is possible to set properties inline. Like `onSubmit`.

Comment: To allow using `setProps()` on the tested component props can be passed down to it like this:
`const TestContext = ({children, ...props}) => <Router>{React.cloneElement(children, props)}</Router>`

Answer (score 6):

Testing components which rely on the context can be a little tricky. What I did was to write a wrapper that I used in my tests.

You can find the wrapper below:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class WithContext extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any,
    context: PropTypes.object
  }

  validateChildren () {
    if (this.props.children === undefined) {
      throw new Error('No child components were passed into WithContext')
    }
    if (this.props.children.length > 1) {
      throw new Error('You can only pass one child component into WithContext')
    }
  }

  render () {
    class WithContext extends React.Component {
      getChildContext () {
        return this.props.context
      }

      render () {
        return this.props.children
      }
    }

    const context = this.props.context

    WithContext.childContextTypes = {}

    for (let propertyName in context) {
      WithContext.childContextTypes[propertyName] = PropTypes.any
    }

    this.validateChildren()

    return (
      <WithContext context={this.props.context}>
        {this.props.children}
      </WithContext>
    )
  }
}
```

Here you can see a sample usage:

```
  <WithContext context={{ location: {pathname: '/Michael/Jackson/lives' }}}>
    <MoonwalkComponent />
  </WithContext>

  <WithContext context={{ router: { isActive: true }}}>
    <YourTestComponent />
  </WithContext>
```

And it should work as you would expect.

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://github.com/pshrmn/react-router-test-context for that exact purpose

"Create a pseudo context object that duplicates React Router's context.router structure. This is useful for shallow unit testing with Enzyme."

After installing it, you will be able to do something like

```
describe('my test', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    const context = createRouterContext()
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />, { context })
  })
})
```

Comment: "Note: This package only works with React Router v4."